# nhibernate sessionfactory instance more than once on web service

Tags: web-services, nhibernate, singleton, asmx, sessionfactory

I have a web service that use nhibernate. I have a singleton pattern on the repositorry library but on each call the service, it creates a new instance of the session factory which is very expensive. What can i do?

```
    #region Atributos

    /// <summary>
    /// Session
    /// </summary>
    private ISession miSession;

    /// <summary>
    /// Session Factory
    /// </summary>
    private ISessionFactory miSessionFactory;
    private Configuration miConfiguration = new Configuration();
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(NHibernatePersistencia).Name);

    private static IRepositorio Repositorio;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    private NHibernatePersistencia()
    {
        //miConfiguration.Configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        try
        {
            miConfiguration.Configure();
            this.miSessionFactory = miConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();
            this.miSession = this.SessionFactory.OpenSession();
            log.Debug("Se carga NHibernate");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("No se pudo cargar Nhibernate " + ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }

    }

    public static IRepositorio Instancia
    {
        get
        {
            if (Repositorio == null)
            {
                Repositorio = new NHibernatePersistencia();
            }
            return Repositorio;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Propiedades

    /// <summary>
    /// Sesion de NHibernate
    /// </summary>
    public ISession Session
    {
        get { return miSession.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession(); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sesion de NHibernate
    /// </summary>
    public ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get { return this.miSessionFactory; }
    }

    #endregion
```

In which way can i create a single instance for all services?

Comment: Suggestion: don't use "throw ex;". You want "throw;". Otherwise, the stack trace will look like the exception came from the location of the "throw ex;"

Answer (score 1):

i think you already mentioned the solution. You have to use a Singleton for the Sessionfactory-Provider. Personally i prefer to use Spring to manage my ApplicationContext an wire my objects but you don't have to. Simply don't use the NHibernatePersistencia-Object as a Service but as a SessionProvider and you are fine.

Your Service could look like this:

```
public class YourService : IYourService
{
    public User GetUsers(int id)
    {
        using(NHibernatePersistencia.OpenSession())
        {
            return session.Load(typeof(user), id);
        }
    }      
}
```

...and for you SessionProvider i'd suggest to always open new sessions per request. Long term sessions are slow and growing. Considering multiple users in a webservice this does not seem to be a good idea.

```
public class NHibernatePersistencia
{
    /* ...  */
    public ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return this.SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
    /* ...  */
}
```

It's simple but should work. Maybe you want to take a look at this [nhibernate.info example](http://nhibernate.info/doc/tutorials/first-nh-app/your-first-nhibernate-based-application). The NHibernateHelper there is pretty much like your NHibernatePersistencia-Class.